# AWS RDS: Can't connect the server with the Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to connect the server with the RDS PostgreSQL instance and receive the 403 error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

This is how the DB instance looks like:

[image]

[image]

This is my server code that I use to connect to the database:

```
const express = require('express');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const config = require('./config');
const path = require('path');
const contacts = require('./contacts');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cors());
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    'postgres://postgres:postgres@database-7.c12fg7kpjsdj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres'
);
```

The VPC security group is here:

[image]

[image]

The IAM user permission is provided:

[image]

What should I check for the reasons that I receive the 403 forbidden error?

Comment: "403" sounds like an HTTP error, but you have not described any HTTP servers or clients.

Comment: Your security group allows inbound traffic from a single IP address. Is that the IP address of whatever machine is running the code? Where is it running from, locally? Lambda? Are you sure it is in fact the postgres connection attempt that is resulting in that error?

Comment: The IP is for the machine that runs the server and tries to connect to the DB.  

I can't there can't be any other reason for 403 error than the server can't reach out the DB.